# find out the closest date and time slot response in flutter

Tags: datetime, dart

I am working on a probability game. I have a date range of the slots to guess the date. Each dates are further dividing into the hour interval (2, 4, 6, 8, 12, 24) to get multiple no of slots. User can select no of slots to reserve.

I have a selected date and time and I want to find out the closest **duration** slot from the user reserved slots array .

```
const selectedDateTime = "2021-01-16 02:50 AM";
const reservedSlots = [
  {"guessHour": 0 - 6, "guessDate": "2021-12-15"},
  {"guessHour": 6 - 12, "guessDate": "2021-12-15"},
  {"guessHour": 18 - 24, "guessDate": "2021-12-15"},
  {"guessHour": 0 - 6, "guessDate": "2021-12-17"},
  {"guessHour": 12 - 18, "guessDate": "2021-12-17"},
  {"guessHour": 0 - 6, "guessDate": "2021-12-18"},
];

const outPut = {"guessHour": 18 - 24, "guessDate": "2021-12-15"};
```

The duration from `selectedDateTime` to `outPut` is less than other the items in `reservedSlots`.

How can I achieve this using dart?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function to get the closes slot. It gets list of slots and a `DateTime` which is the time user selected, computes the differences between user's selected time and slots and returns the closest one.

```
import 'dart:math';

Map<String, String> getClosestSlot(
    List<Map<String, String>> slots, DateTime selected) {
  final differences = slots.map((e) {
    final List<int> hours =
        e['guessHour']!.split(' - ').map((e) => int.parse(e)).toList();
    final date1 =
        DateTime.parse(e['guessDate']!).add(Duration(hours: hours.first));
    final date2 =
        DateTime.parse(e['guessDate']!).add(Duration(hours: hours.last));
    return min(date1.difference(selected).abs().inSeconds,
        date2.difference(selected).abs().inSeconds);
  }).toList();
  final minDifference = differences.reduce(min);
  final minIndex = differences.indexOf(minDifference);
  return slots[minIndex];
}

void main() {
  final selectedDateTime = DateTime(2021, 12, 16, 2, 50);

  const reservedSlots = [
    {"guessHour": "0 - 6", "guessDate": "2021-12-15"},
    {"guessHour": "6 - 12", "guessDate": "2021-12-15"},
    {"guessHour": "18 - 24", "guessDate": "2021-12-15"},
    {"guessHour": "0 - 6", "guessDate": "2021-12-17"},
    {"guessHour": "12 - 18", "guessDate": "2021-12-17"},
    {"guessHour": "0 - 6", "guessDate": "2021-12-18"},
  ];

  final closestSlot = getClosestSlot(reservedSlots, selectedDateTime);
  print(closestSlot);
}
```

Comment: final selectedDateTime = DateTime.parse("2021-01-16 02:50:00");

  const reservedSlots = [
    {"guessHour": "0 - 6", "guessDate": "2021-12-15"},
    {"guessHour": "6 - 12", "guessDate": "2021-12-15"},
    {"guessHour": "18 - 24", "guessDate": "2021-12-15"},
    {"guessHour": "0 - 6", "guessDate": "2021-12-16"},
    {"guessHour": "0 - 6", "guessDate": "2021-12-17"},
    {"guessHour": "12 - 18", "guessDate": "2021-12-17"},
    {"guessHour": "0 - 6", "guessDate": "2021-12-18"},
  ];

  final closestSlot = getClosestSlot(reservedSlots, selectedDateTime);
  print(closestSlot);

Comment: Output: {"guessHour": "0 - 6", "guessDate": "2021-12-16"},

Comment: I tried the exact code you commented and got correct output. Test it again and make sure you're using the correct function I've posted in my answer. @MrutyunjayaGiri